# need to insert a word to a specific line at the end in a file from a remote ssh

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, tee

i have a file like below

```
cat test -(X- different words )
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
always-a-constant:::pete
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

i need to add steve next to pete and generate a new file and the output should look like the below.

```
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    always-a-constant:::pete,steve
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I can use awk

```
cat  test | grep -i alw|  awk '{print $0",steve"}' 
always-a-constant:::pete,steve
```

but i still need the other lines XXX .

Comment: show you current attempts

Comment: cat  test | grep -i alw|  awk '{print $0",steve"}' 
always-a-constant:::pete,steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1: sed

With this as our test file:

```
$ cat test
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
always-a-constant:::pete
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

We can add `,steve` after any line that starts with `alw` with:

```
$ sed '/^alw/ s/$/,steve/' test
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
always-a-constant:::pete,steve
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In sed's regular expressions, `$` matches at the end of a line.  Thus, `s/$/,steve/` adds `,steve` on at the end of the line.

#### Method 2: awk

```
$ awk '/^alw/ {$0=$0",steve"} 1' test
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
always-a-constant:::pete,steve
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In awk, `$0` represents the current line.  `$0",steve"` represents the current line followed by the string `.steve`.  Thus, `$0=$0",steve"` replaces the current line with the current line followed by `,steve`.

The final `1` in the awk command is important: it is awk's shorthand for print-the-line. Any non-zero number would work. In more detail, awk treats the `1` as a condition (a boolean). Because it evaluates to true (nonzero), the action is performed. Since we didn't actually specify an action, awk performs the default action which is to print the line. Hence, 1 is shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Method 3: sed

Alternatively, we can add `,steve` after any line that ends with `:::pete` with:

```
$ sed 's/:::pete/&,steve/' test
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
always-a-constant:::pete,steve
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: thanks, it'll be useful if you tell the use of ' $ ' in sed and $0=$0 in the commands respectively.

Comment: @Steve_0404 You're welcome.  Also, I just added a couple paragraphs to the answer to explain the `$` and `$0` terms.

Comment: and the use of 1 in awk ? i replace with any number i get the output. if it's not der we dont get the output

Comment: @Steve_0404 That is exactly correct:  the `1` functions as shorthand for print-the-line.  Any non-zero number would work.  In more detail, awk treats the `1` as a condition (a boolean).  Because it evaluates to true, the action is performed.  Since we didn't actually specify an action, awk performs the default action which is to print the line.  Hence, `1` is shorthand for print-the-line.

Comment: Thanks John, u rock !